# Crawl documents stored as SQL Server FileTables

Tags: fast-search

Is it possible to crawl documents stored in a SQL Server FileTables table from its network share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As filetable stored the data on the fileshare then you can create the content source for file share and crawl the items from that location.
how to configure the Search for fileshare read this.

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/07/01/how-to-configure-enterprise-search-to-index-a-file-share.aspx

Another option i am thinking may be BCS. Check this [Searching External Data in SharePoint 2010 Using Business Connectivity Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/04/30/searching-external-data-in-sharepoint-2010-using-business-connectivity-services.aspx)